# No IP address for eth0 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I cannot obtain an IP address for eth0 on Uuntu 16.04. I'm connected to the router.

This is what I get from ifconfig:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:69:e0:b3  
              inet6 addr: 2a01:388:350:111::1:17/128 Scope:Global
              inet6 addr: fe80::d92b:2c51:626e:202f/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:48359 (48.3 KB)  TX bytes:9200 (9.2 KB)
```

In /etc/network/interfaces i have this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have this in the interface file

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules`

Since right now you only have a loopback interface setup

Comment: Now it does not show the ethernet connection icon in taskbar even if it seems to be connected (i have "disconnect" option), and the name changed: "ifupdown(eth0)".

Answer (score 0):

My MAC address was not registered for connection to the wired network which is why I could not connect on the ports I had been trying.